# Given the PDF of $X + Y$, how can you easily calculate the PDF of $X - Y$?

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions, convolution, density-function

The question is as follows:

> Consider a PDF that is positive only within an interval $[a, b]$ and is
> symmetric around the mean $(a + b)/2$. Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables
> that both have this PDF. Suppose that you have calculated the PDF of $X + Y$. How
> can you easily obtain the PDF of $X - Y$?

This is in the convolution section of the book which introduces the theorem that the PDF of $Z_1$ given $Z_1 = X + Y$ is:
$$f_{Z_1}(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)dx$$

I initially tried to do this by representing $Z_2=X-Y$ as a convolution of the two PDFs:
$$f_{Z_2}(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x)f_Y(x-z)dx$$

However, I was not sure where to go from here. In the book they give this as the solution:

> We have $X −Y = X +Z −(a+b)$, where $Z = a+b−Y$
> is distributed identically with $X$ and $Y$ . Thus, the PDF of $X + Z$ is the same as the
> PDF of $X + Y$ , and the PDF of $X − Y$ is obtained by shifting the PDF of $X + Y$ to
> the left by $a + b$.

I don't quite understand the solution. How did they get $Z = a+b−Y$ and why is $X + Z$ the same as $X + Y$?

Comment: $Z=a+b-Y$ is an rv that is identically distributed with $Y$, by the symmetry of the distribution of $Y$. Then $X-Y=X+Z-(a+b)$. Since $Z$ and $Y$ have the same distribution, and both are independent of $X$, so do $X+Z$ and $X+Y$.

Comment: Oh I see, because $Z$ is simply $Y$ flipped along the vertical axis and then shifted to the right by $a+b$, thereby, going back to the same mean position as $Y$. And from symmetry, $Z=Y$?

Comment: No, $\ Z\ $ is not *equal* to $\ Y\ $. It merely has *the same distribution* as both $\ X\ $ and $\ Y\ $, and is independent of $\ X\ $ because $\ Y\ $ is.   Since $\ Z\ $ is *defined* to be $\ a+b-Y\ $ it could only be equal to $\ Y\ $ if both were equal to $\ \frac{a+b}{2}\ $ with probability $1$, which is impossible, because their distribution could not then have a density function.  However, because the pair of random variables $\ X,Z\ $ have the same bivariate distribution as $\ X,Y\ $, it follows that $\ X+Z\ $ must have the same distribution as $\ Z_1=X+Y\ $.